# How to expand environment variable %CommonProgramFiles%\system\ in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a situation where I need to return a directory path by reading the registry settings. Registry value returns me a path in the format

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\System\web32.dll
```

while the consumer code is expecting it in the format

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\web32.dll
```

How can I resolve such directory path in .net code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx). If you control the creation of the registry value, store it as an expandable string in the registry and the registry API will automatically expand it for you.

Comment: I need a full directory path and it could be any other environment variable, not just %CommonProgramFiles%

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @Faisal. `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` will expand any environment variable it sees in the string you supply, and will yield a full path in the specific case you cite in the question.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) function:

```
string commonDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CommonProgramFiles");
```

You can then use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to append the rest of the path:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(commonDir, "System", "web32.dll");
```

Another option is to use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx). This will replace all environment variables with their values:

```
string fullPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%CommonProgramFiles%\System\web32.dll");
```

Comment: Of course, that override of `Path.Combine` only works in v4 of the framework