# VB.NET 2010 - Process.Start("filePath\Test.bat") not opening test.bat?

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on some vb.net 2010 coding and I am stuck on a piece of code that I dont know how to fix it, so thats why I ask you to maybe help me with this code.

Code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim url As New System.Uri("http://example/one/")
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
    req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\examplepath"
    Try
        resp = req.GetResponse()
        resp.Close()
        req = Nothing
        Process.Start("filePath\Test.exe")
    Catch ex As Exception
        req = Nothing
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Problem:
The file in %APPDATA%\ExamplePath\Test.bat doesn't open.

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems the problem:

> ```
> Process.Start("filePath\Test.exe")
> ```

Here you're putting a variable as a string, which of course won't work. Instead, concatenate it with the file name:

```
Process.Start(filePath & "\Test.exe")
```

That will work, but a better way to handle the file system is to use the `Path` class and the `Combine` method to handle a path that has multiple parts:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(filePath, "Test.exe"))
```

This deals with putting the correct separator and the fact that it may or may not have a trailing backslash.

Comment: Thank you! You helped my out of this 1 month situation!

Comment: deleted my comment to avoid confusion :)

Comment: @Alex is there a way to add the %USERNAME% vairaible to   `Dim url As New System.Uri("http://example/%USERNAME%/")`??

Comment: @Luseres You need to expand the variables first, then call Process.Start. Look at this question for some details on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2707447/2557263

Comment: @Luseres Dim url As New System.Uri("http://exmple/" & Environment.UserName & "/")nthat is what you are looking for. edit for some reson it adds a ; after example, pls ignore that

Comment: @Alex I used  `Dim url As New System.Uri("http://example/PC/" & Environment.MachineName & "/Debug.txt/")` and I created a Debug.txt in my ftp but the file doesnt open. Do you know the problem

Comment: Try it without the http:// in front, and use backslashes, like this : `"\\example\PC\" & Environment.MachineName & "\Debug.txt\"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use cmd for opening batfiles:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c foobar/test.bat")
```

be carefull, if the filepath contains spaces you have to add extra "" to make it work:)
your problem was, that a .bat file is not a process to start, only a file

Comment: and what if I want it to be a .exe?

Comment: for that use haidis answer, putthe filepath in the workind directory and the exe file in the Filename.

Comment: `Process.Start("<any file>")`, like any other way of creating a process, will invoke a handler which opens the specified file in its default program, so your statement: `your problem was, that a .bat file is not a process to start, only a file` is incorrect.

Comment: All file types (even `.exe`-applications) have a key in the registry which tells Windows what to do with such a file if you attempt to open it. `.exe`-files are just told to invoke themselves. -- You can actually remove the key for `.exe`-files from the registry, and doing so will make you unable to start any application.

Comment: i didnt know that Process.start would look up the handler for the specified file. Thank you for the information

Comment: @Alex : No problem, we're here to learn :). `Process.Start()` internally calls [**`ShellExecute()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx), which will lookup the handler (apparently referred to as a "verb") in the registry. The default verb is `open`, and quoting the docs, it: `Launches an application. If this file is not an executable file, its associated application is launched.`

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring a new process and specify the `WorkingDirectory` property.

Use the following code to achieve this

```
Dim myProcess As New Process
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Test.bat"
myProcess.Start()
```

Comment: But how do I get it to %APPDATA%

Comment: Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`